# Use JBoss JPA 2.1 on JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: hibernate, persistence, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss AS 7.1 and JBoss EAP 6.1. I packaged all libraries and classes in one WAR file and deployed it in two application servers. When I run the same codes inside WAR on AS 7.1, it is working fine, but not on EAP 6.1. I use JBoss JPA for the persistence entity (many-to-one and one-to-many). Is it because EAP uses different way to implement JPA? Any hints or directions are appreciated. The method which creates the errors is as follows:

```
/**
 * Attempts to store the entity object into the database.
 * 
 * @param entity BaseEntity object.
 * @throws ValidationException Thrown if we encounter a persistence error
 */
public void persist( BaseEntity entity ) throws ValidationException {
    boolean isCreate = false;
    try {
        final EntityManager em = entityManager;
        if ( null == entity.getId() ) {
            isCreate = true;
            entity.setCreateDateTime( new java.util.Date() );
            entity.setCreateUser( SecurityUtil.getCurrentUser() );
            em.persist( entity );               
            List<DistinguishedName> list = createDNs( entity );
            for (DistinguishedName dn : list) {
                em.persist( dn );
            }
        } else {
            entity.setLastUpdateDateTime( new java.util.Date() );
            entity.setLastUpdateUser(  SecurityUtil.getCurrentUser() );
            em.merge( entity );
        }
        em.flush();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        rollback();
        if ( null != e.getCause() && null != e.getCause().getCause() ) {
            if ( e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException ) {
                throw new ConstraintValidationException( MessageBundleEnum.BUSINESSLOGIC.getMessage( "InvalidConstraint" ), e );
            } else if ( e.getCause().getCause() instanceof StaleObjectStateException ) {
                throw new EntityOutOfDateException( MessageBundleEnum.BUSINESSLOGIC.getMessage( "outOfDate" ), e );
            }
        }
        throw new ValidationException( MessageBundleEnum.BUSINESSLOGIC.getMessage( "generalError", e.getMessage() ), e );
    }

    if ( isCreate ) {
        raiseEvent(new CreatedEvent(), entity);
    } else {
        raiseEvent(new UpdatedEvent(), entity);
    }
}
```

Here is the error on EAP 6.1:

```
15:09:28,446 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 458878
15:09:35,355 SEVERE [com.test.function.application.network.ManageNetwork] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) An error has occurred: Unable to find com.test.function.domain.PhysicalPhysicalXref with id 458878.: com.test.function.exception.businesslogic.ValidationException: An error has occurred: Unable to find com.test.function.domain.PhysicalPhysicalXref with id 458878.
    at com.test.function.persistence.PersistenceService.persist(PersistenceService.java:183) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at com.test.function.persistence.PersistenceService.persist(PersistenceService.java:201) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:129) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:74) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:226) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:317) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:214) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at com.test.function.persistence.PersistenceService$$$view20.persist(Unknown Source) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at com.test.function.service.lim.network.ManageNetworkService.save(ManageNetworkService.java:162) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:129) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:74) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:248) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:315) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:214) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at com.test.function.service.lim.network.ManageNetworkService$$$view9.save(Unknown Source) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.test.function.service.lim.network.ManageNetworkService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.save(ManageNetworkService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at com.test.function.application.BaseManageNetwork.save(BaseManageNetwork.java:289) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at com.test.function.application.network.ManageNetwork$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(ManageNetwork$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [function-0.22.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.13.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.13.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
```

Comment: have u resolved this problem?